# How can I access c++ class member function from lua script?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua

I think the problem I want to solve will an easy one for most of you:)
Suppose I have a class `Node` which has a member function `setPosition(float x, float y, float z)`. I would like to be able to define a variable of class Node in lua and then be able to use `setPosition()` function also form the Lua. 
I know that there are issues that Lua is rather for C not C++ and has its issues with C++ classes but I also know that it is achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html) for this.  With it you can easily bind C++ classes so they can be created, accessed, and modified in Lua.  The code you'd write in C++ might look roughly like this:

```
module(L) [
    class_<Node>
        .def(constructor<>)
        .def("setPosition", &Node::setPosition)
];
```

Then you'd be able to say this in Lua:

```
node = Node()
node:setPosition(x, y, z)
```

You could also make bindings so that the Lua looks a little more natural and could support things like these:

```
node1 = Node(x, y, z)
node2 = Node()
node2.position = { x, y, z }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already built and included luabind to my project but the problem is that I have my "game engine" in c++, I have my RenderSystem (variable) in there already defined and I wasnt to access it and call something like this : `Body x = RenderSystem->createBody();` I know already how can I expose a class with Luabind but how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Then you should make a binding (perhaps using Luabind) for the RenderSystem class and its createBody function, and then you can call it from Lua and operate on the result.  Or perhaps I am misunderstanding what you're looking for?